# Change of variables and the expected value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, change-of-variable

We have a non-negative random variable $z$. We apply a simple location/scale transformation with $a$ and $b$ being the transformation parameters, respectively.

I am trying to show that this change-of-variables argument is true for any function $f$

$$E_{\text{base}}f(a+bz)=E_{\text{transformed}}f(z),$$

where $E$ is the expected value under the base and transformed distributions.

I started with the definition of the expected value
$$E_{\text{base}}f(a+bz)=\int f(a+bz)P_{\text{base}}(z)dz$$
and
$$E_{\text{transformed}}f(z)=\int f(z)P_{\text{transformed}}(z)dz$$

If we define $u=a+bz$, then we can write
$$E_{\text{base}}f(u)=\int f(u)P_{\text{base}}(\frac{u-a}{b})\frac{1}{b}du$$

But now what?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You are done if you can prove, that
$$P_{\text{transformed}}(u) = P_{\text{base}}(\frac{u-a}{b})\frac{1}{b}.$$